# wordpress javascript load order

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, grid

I have those scripts loading for a grid in wordpress..

```
<script src="/wp-includes/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="/wp-includes/js/colorfinder-1.1.js"></script>
<script src="/wp-includes/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"</script>
<script src="/wp-includes/js/classie.js"></script>
<script src="/wp-includes/js/gridScrollFx.js"></script>
<script>new GridScrollFx( document.getElementById( 'grid' ), { viewportFactor : 0.4 } );</script>
```

And.. They work fine on a simple HTML page, but if I move everything to wordpress I get an error; "Uncaught ReferenceError: classie is not defined"

So I suppose that is because it hasn't loaded classie.js before moving on to gridscrollfx, but why if it's before it? It works on html but no on wordpress.

Btw, I tried moving it up and down but it just doesn't work, comes up with similar errors.

Answer (score 1):

You have not completed the closing tag in one script tag:

```
<script src="/wp-includes/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="/wp-includes/js/colorfinder-1.1.js"></script>
<script src="/wp-includes/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script> <!-- Close script tag here after quotes -->
<script src="/wp-includes/js/classie.js"></script>
<script src="/wp-includes/js/gridScrollFx.js"></script>
```

Comment: Omg, I'm so so sorry. I've not spotted this one. All works, thanks man!

Comment: @user3488750 not OP, but please accept the answer to reward the answerer(OP)